# Trouble coercing input to matrix for DBSCAN for grouped dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr, outliers, dbscan

I'm trying to apply dbscan to a data frame using a function that contains multiple groups however I'm getting an error saying that x must be a matrix:

```
Adding missing grouping variables: `group`
Error in `summarise()`:
! Problem while computing `outlier_index = list(detect_outliers(.))`.
i The error occurred in group 1: group = "a".
Caused by error in `dbscan::dbscan()`:
! x has to be a numeric matrix.
```

I've checked the help documents for dbscan an it appears as though a dataframe can be used as the x argument:

[image]

My function takes a data frame, a var to group on and 2 additional arguments to calculate whether each point is an outlier or not.

Here's a sample dataset which replicates the data I'm using:

```
df <- data.frame(
  group = rep(letters[1:3], each = 10),
  value1 = rnorm(30),
  value2 = rnorm(30),
  value3 = rnorm(30)
)
```

Here's the function I've defined:

```
# INSTALL PACMAN
if (!require("pacman", character.only = TRUE)) {
  install.packages("pacman")
}

# LOAD THE NECESSARY LIBRARIES
pacman::p_load(dplyr, dbscan)

remove_outliers <- function(data, group_var, outlier_threshold, outlier_cols) {
  # DEFINE A FUNCTION TO REMOVE OUTLIERS
  detect_outliers <- function(x) {
    #x_num <- as.matrix(select(x, {{ outlier_cols }}))
    outlier_index <- which(dbscan::dbscan(x, eps = outlier_threshold, minPts = 5)$cluster == -1)
    return(outlier_index)
  }
  # GROUP BY GROUP AND APPLY THE DETECT OUTLIER FUNCTION TO EACH GROUP
  outliers <- data %>%
    group_by(across({{ group_var }})) %>%
    summarise(outlier_index = list(detect_outliers(.)))

  # UNNEST THE OUTLIERS DATA FRAME AND REMOVE ANY OUTLIER POINTS
  data_clean <- data %>%
    left_join(outliers %>% unnest(outlier_index), by = {{ group_var }}) %>%
    filter(is.na(outlier_index))

  return(data_clean)
}
```

I'm then using this function using this call:

```
test <- remove_outliers(data = df, group_var = group, outlier_threshold = 2, outlier_cols = c("value1", "value3"))
```

As per the help file, my input df is a data frame and I've also explicitly tried converting the input `outlier_cols` to a matrix by adding the commented columns in the `detect_outlier` function.

Any help that could get me past this error would be greatly appreciated.